# Tkinter - How can I make a button can create new window and close the main window

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello guys I want to make a button can close the main window (window01) and create new window (window02)
This is my code but he does not working with me :

```
from tkinter import *
window01 = Tk()
def myButton():
   window02 = tk.Toplevel(window01)
   
button = Button(window01, text="Button", command=myButton)
button.pack()
window01.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"close the main window"*? Does it mean to destroy the main window or just hide it without destroying it?

Comment: If you destroy the main window, the new window dies with it, instead you can either hide the main window, or create a new main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def myButton():
    window01.destroy()
    window02 = tk.Tk()
    # Code for your second window
    window02.mainloop()

window01 = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(window01, text="Button", command=myButton)
button.pack()
window01.mainloop()
```

When the button is clicked it destroys `window01` and creates `window02` and goes in `window02`'s mainloop.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-Paste dupli-duplication of your code:

```
from tkinter import *

nextStep = False

window01 = Tk()
def myButton():
   global nextStep
   nextStep = True
   window01.destroy()
   
button = Button(window01, text="Button", command=myButton)
button.pack()
window01.mainloop()

if nextStep:
   window01 = Tk()
   button = Button(window01, text="Button", command=myButton)
   button.pack()
   window01.mainloop()
```

If you just close the first window directly, nothing happens, if you press the button, the second window appears.

Comment: don't work I want to close the main window and create a new

Comment: That's just the copy-paste for the example. I did not invent different content for the new window, but inside `if nextStep:` you can certainly pick a different name and different content for the second window created.

Comment: @YasserKad this should work as the code that is after the call to `mainloop` will get executed after the main event loop is killed. If you press the button it sets the flag to `True`, which will help in opening the new window once this has been destroyed.